# What is more Powerful power of fear or fear of power..?

Tags: ethics

the basic question is what affects a person more

- Power of fear i.e when he is afraid of something.. something from his pasts or something he fears which might happen in future..
- Fear of power i.e that powers will corrupt his mind and he will lose sight to whats important..

Comment: Could I persuade you to describe the context of your question? It is akin to asking which is more important: the meaning of force, or the force of meaning. It may sound poetic, but the two things are not meaningful to compare without some motivating background.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about comparing two disparate phenomena of psychology in an unclear way.

Comment: There is a serious equivocation between two senses of the term "power", and this renders the question itself, "what is more powerful", ambiguous, making it impossible to answer without further clarification by the author.  My sense is that the author is both not aware of this equivocation, as well as trying to trade in this equivocation in the belief that it has philosophical merit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acording your definition, Power of fear.

Because to make sense, you must ask 1) Power of fear vs 2) Power of fear of power.
And then its clear that if you are affect by 2) you are affected by 1) but if you are affected by 1) it does not have to be 2). So total effect is trivialy greater.